# Check if app is run by sudo/admin on Linux

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, .net-core, windows-identity

I am trying to check if .Net code is running as sudo/admin on Linux. It works on Windows but throws exception on Linux.

How do I check if app is run by admin/sudo on Ubuntu Linux by using .NET Core2.0 build-in class?

Here is the code I have tried:

```cs
using System;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace smallTestsCore
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Program.IsAdministrator);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static bool IsAdministrator =>
            new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
                .IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
    }
}
```

The code works on Windows, but does not work on Linux:

```cs
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.PlatformNotSupportedException
An unhandled exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' occurred in
System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll: 'Windows Principal functionality is not supported on this platform.'
  at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
   at adminTst.Program.get_IsAdministrator() in /home/user/adminTst/Program.cs:line 15
   at adminTst.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/user/adminTst/Program.cs:line 11
```

Answer (score 0):

I give the answer for those who, like me, are looking for an answer these days, and end up on this post.

Of course, this solution may not be 100% suitable, but usually, in most cases, the problem is solved by **checking the user id for 0**.

For example, you can check the user id like this: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/25118#issuecomment-367407469

> To check if you are running as root on Unix:
>
> 1. add a PackageReference to Mono.Posix.NETStandard
> 2. Change IsAdminstrator to the following:

```
public static bool IsAdministrator =>
    RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows) ?
        new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
            .IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator) :
        Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall.geteuid() == 0;
```